# The best way to create pages like an 'about', 'contact' and etc

Tags: page-template, template-hierarchy, author-template

I develop my own theme and I need to create nice looking sites like a contact page or about me page. But I don't have any idea what wordpress template file I can use. Will I have to use page-template or something else?

How do they do a premium themes?

Comment: Please ask a question to wordpress.org forums. That will be a more suitable place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-a-custom-page-template-for-one-specific-page) should help get you started:

> As mentioned in the Template Hierarchy page, you can create a template
>   for a specific page.  To create a template for one specific page, copy
>   your existing `page.php` file and rename it with your page’s slug or ID:
>
> 1. `page-{slug}.php`
> 2. `page-{ID}.php`
>
> For example: Your About page has a slug
>   of ‘about’ and an ID of 6. If your active theme’s folder has a file
>   named `page-about.php` or `page-6.php`, then WordPress will automatically
>   find and use that file to render the About page.

Comment: I know template hierarchy. I know also page-{$slug}.php, but when I create site this way, so users who will download my theme will haven't nice looking page. I would like to know more how premium themes do it.

Comment: @yelidric - Which theme? There is no standard that they all follow. Some use global template files, some use Shortcodes, some use page builder plugins.

Comment: Which theme? If u think premium theme, so its doesn't matter. How I wrote above, I develop own theme which users can download.

Comment: I would suggest doing some more research on the different ways to accomplish this, then choosing the solution that works best for you. As @Milo said, there is no single right answer.

Comment: And do u have any ideas or tips?